# Release efficiently pointers from the pointed object itself

Tags: c++, pointers, merge, linked-list

I've got a class that I use in order to create sets of linked objects. The "linking" is performed in such a way that the pointer `link` of every object of a given set points to one same object of the class (which will be called "the head" from now on). Thus, when an object of the set is accessed, it will in turn give access to the head and, therefore, to `data_`, contained in the head (a sort of linked list, but where all the objects are linked to one single object, instead of being linked to the next one of a list).

The class looks like this:

```
template <typename T> class Myclass;

template <typename T>
class Myclass
{
    Myclass<T>* link;
    shared_ptr<T> data_;
    int count_;

    Myclass<T>* rep()
    {
        if(link==0x00) return this;
        else
        {
            Myclass* ret = link->rep();
            return link = ret;
        }
    }

public:

    Myclass()
    : link(0x00)
    , count_(1)
    {}

    explicit Myclass(const shared_ptr<T>& data)
    : link(0x00)
    , data_(data)
    , count_(1)
    {}

(...more functions)

    void add(Myclass<T>& rv)
    {
        if(*this == rv) return;
        rv.data() = shared_ptr<T>();
        rep()->count_ += rv.empty() ? 1 : rv.count();
        rv.count_ = 0;

        rv.rep()->link = rep();
    }

    shared_ptr<T>& data()
    {
        return rep()->data_;
    }
}
```

A "head" is created when an object of `Myclass` is invoked by the constructor `explicit Myclass(const shared_ptr<T>& data)`, and `data_` is filled with `const shared_ptr<T>& data`. The method `add()` adds an object of `Myclass` to a set, by linking it to the head of the set. The "linking" is actually done by `rep()`, as you can see in the code. Any public function of the class does its stuff through `rep()`, like in `data()`. Thus, I can access to `data_` from any object of a set.

The thing is, when handling one object of a set of `Myclass` somewhere in the code, I may need to break up the set. To break up the set means for me that all the objects of that set get unliked from the head (i.e., the variable `link` does not point to the head anymore) and also the `data_` of the head is freed (so it is no head anymore). The setback here is that I  only have access to the object I am handling and to the head, (by means of `rep()`).

How can I carry out this breaking-up when I only have access to one object of the set?

The only idea I have come up with is to create another variable in the class, a vector of pointers `Myclass<T>*`. Every time an object is added to a set, the vector of the head is increased with a pointer to this brand new object. So, when I want to "dissolve" a set I just have to fix, through these pointers, the variable `link` of each object to `0x00`. However, I am pretty sure it must be other more elegant and optimised way to do it.

Any idea will be more than welcome. Hope that I have explained my problem clearly enough.

Comment: Why do you represent the objects in this manner?, what advantage does it have?

Comment: I have no idea what data structure you are trying to create. You say it's sort of like a linked list, but then what's the difference?

Comment: Your question is not clear but your ownership semantics seem incomplete. You should consider declaring `link` as a `std::weak_ptr` otherwise you're likely going to run into problems with circular references.

Comment: @GearoidMurphy:This class is created in a 3D Reconstruction context. The objects of `Myclass` are associated to 2D point of images, and `data_` is a structure with information about the 3D point. I thought it was a suitable way to solve the association data problem that exists between a 3D point and the 2D points that "see it". There are, in my opinion, 3 main advantages:
  1. Any object of `Myclass`can become a "head" of a set.
  2. It is possible to access to the 3D point structure through 
     any object of the set.
  3. It is possible to track which images are "seeing" the 3D point.

Comment: @rwols: In a linked list, an object is linked to another object which, in turn, is linked to _another_ object. In `Myclass` all the objects of a set are linked to "the head", as I said.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: yeah, I was afraid that my redaction might be a bit obscure. Sorry, it must be the language barrier :). I have edited it, hope now is clearer. And thanks for the warning about circular references!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue fully, you should be able to do this the safest and easiest with a smart pointer (like C++11's shared_ptr and related classes).

Comment: Sorry, but I can't figure out how to use smart pointers here. Maybe by using `intrusive_ptr`, that keeps the reference count in the object? Anyway, a smart pointer doesn't fix the issue of unlinking the objects of a set from the head, does it? Could you develop your answer? Thanks!